# howto create a multidimensional Array of floats with Pythonnet

Tags: python, .net, multidimensional-array, ironpython, python.net

I'm using pythonnet (http://pythonnet.sf.net) to bind together a python framework and a .NET library (I know if IronPython but this is not the question).

Using pythonnet, I can create an Array of floats, and initialize it from a sequence of values:

```
>>> from System import *
>>> Array[float]([1., 2.])
<System.Double[] object at 0x8a6c46c>
```

I need to pass an 3x3 array of floats to a method in the the .NET library, and I can't figure out how to create this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Array.CreateInstance:

```
>>> a = Array.CreateInstance(Double, 3, 3)
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: That would create an empty 3x3 array though. How do you assign existing array values to the array?

Comment: @Jonno a.SetValue(value,pos)